# How to iframe a youtube video in HTML for Android phones to be able to watch and rotate full screen?

Tags: android, iframe, youtube, fullscreen, rotation

i'm experiencing some trouble with a new app I develop for iphone and android .
This app is supposed in both cases to take and display the content of my Wordpress blog.
I have different tabs and one of them is "videos" showing all the "videos" category posts.

My problem is :
to embed videos, i use: 
"A `<embed id="yt"  src="http://www.youtube.com/V/..." type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="100%" height="240"></embed>` " in the html part of my posts

A: works perfectly with iphones : video launched directly in full screen and rotated but 
But it DOESN'T Work with Android (blank)

So i tried: `<iframe width="100%" height="240" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed..." frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`"

B: works with Android and  with iphones but CANNOT ROTATE NOR FULL SCREEN

Can anyone help me have an hmtl rotative iframe that can be read by both iphone and android?

Thank you!